# Sed appears to be deleting the full line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting, find

Hi guys I'm trying to use sed to delete part of a string (its a directory). I'm using it like so

```
sed -i 's/$1//g' ~/Desktop/RecyclingBin/logs/$1
```

whenever I open the text file it appears to be blank. Any help would be appreciated..

Also if there's an easier way to output a files location to a text file without the actual filename being in the output that would make life a lot easier currently using:

```
find $PWD -type d -name "*$1*" >> ~/Desktop/RecyclingBin/logs/$1
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: Poor question. We dunno if `$1` is a parameter or should be _literal_. Also, USE MORE QUOTES ! http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting

Comment: Apologies. It's a parameter

Comment: the parameter will be the name of the file so for example if I delete a file called "test" I want the file name inside logs to be "test" and the contents of the file to be the location of where it was stored

Comment: all inside a folder ~Desktop/RecyclingBin/logs. So if I were to delete "test" a file will be inside ~Desktop/RecyclingBin/logs/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in `find` itself:

```
find . -type d -name "*$1*" -exec bash -c 'echo "${1##*/}"' - {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use my example

```
sed -i "s/$1//g" ~/Desktop/RecyclingBin/logs/$1
```

It works for me.

Comment: still getting a blank file

Comment: ok lets get it clear, the string you wrote takes parameter $1, then open file ~/Desktop/RecyclingBin/logs/$1 and then delete in this file pattern $1. Is it what you were expected?

Comment: ill give you a sample of what im doing: The paramater is a file name. The script writes the location of this file into a new file inside the log folder. The script then removes the filename from the directory string inside this new file (/logs/test now becomes /logs/)

Comment: show a trace of the executed line (with a set -vx) for a "empty" file

Answer (score 0):

Always remember, if you want to use a variable in sed expression , you should use "" like the example posted above

Otherwise for normal substitution use single quotes..

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a variable in sed expression , you should use "" like the example posted above. This is the feature of sed

Otherwise for normal substitution use single quotes..

Comment: Using a _shell_ variable inside `"..."` (double-quoted string) is a _shell_ feature, unrelated to `sed` - `sed` - or any other external utility, for that matter - only sees the _result_ of the shell's string interpolation. A `'...'` (single-quoted) string is _also_ a shell feature - only in this case the string contents are passed as-is to `sed` (no interpolation). Understanding the difference between what the shell does up front vs. what `sed` ends up seeing as its script is important.